# Pause before painting the panel in Java

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, paintcomponent, thread-sleep

I am trying to slow down the painting by adding a pause between two consecutive paints. `Thread.sleep()` apparently doesn't work. Here is the code:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class Sa {
    int x = 70;
    int y = 70;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Sa gui = new Sa();
        gui.go();
    }

    public void go() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        MyDrawPanel drawPanel = new MyDrawPanel();
        frame.getContentPane().add(drawPanel);

        frame.setSize(300, 300);
        frame.setVisible(true);

        for(int i=0; i<130; i++) {
            x++;
            y++;
            drawPanel.repaint();
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1500);
            } catch(Exception ex) {}
        }

    }

    class MyDrawPanel extends JPanel {
        public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            g.setColor(Color.white);
            g.fillRect(0, 0, this.getWidth(), this.getHeight());
            Thread.sleep(1500); // will not work!!
            g.setColor(Color.green);
            g.fillOval(x, y, 80, 40);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you looked over this [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html)?  I'm not an expert in this, but I don't think you can do all your Swing stuff directly from the thread that runs the main program, and it looks like that's what you're doing.

Comment: You can't do this.  Sleeping the current thread will stop the Event Dispatching Thread from processing the current paint process.  So nothing will be painted until after the `paintComponent` method has returned.  The question is, why?  What is it you are trying to achieve...??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove `Thread.sleep()` inside `paint()` method, not need it, and second, you `Thread.sleep()` needs to be caught `InterruptedException`, it may give an error while compiling:

```
  g.setColor(Color.white);
    g.fillRect(0, 0, this.getWidth(), this.getHeight());
    //Thread.sleep(1500); // will not work!! (DONT NEED this
    g.setColor(Color.green);
    g.fillOval(x, y, 80, 40);
```

Have you looked at [**Swing Timer**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) ?